# How to solve the network error when using a patch function?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps

I am currently developing an application. This application utilizes the Patch function to update a SharePoint list. When I attempt to patch the fields, I encounter an error message stating: "Network error when using the Patch function, an error occurred on the server."

I have conducted thorough checks and confirmed that the all the column names but still getting the error.

Comment: If you use the [Monitor tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/monitor-overview), do you see some network request with more information from the server which would explain why the request is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Below are some of the reasons you get the network error when using a patch function in Microsoft Power Apps applications:

1. One of the columns in your SharePoint list is required/mandatory and you are not passing any value to this column using Patch function
2. You are not passing the value with correct data type to one of the SharePoint list columns. For example:

   - You have a number column in your SharePoint list and you are passing text value from patch function for the number column
   - You have a date and time column in your SharePoint list and you are passing wrong value from patch function for the this column
3. You have a column or list validation applied in your SharePoint list which is not fulfilled while using Patch function

So, try validating above things once and make sure you are passing valid data while using Patch function.

---

You can also use Monitor tool to know more about network error in Power Apps:

[image]

**Microsoft Documentation**: [Power Apps Monitor overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/monitor-overview)